# How to change BarButtonItem Constraints in UIToolBar

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I have the following UIToolBar above the keyboard once the textfield is selected. To make up for the added height to the UIToolBar I would like to raise the BarButtonItem a bit higher and center it within the new height 80

**In viewDidLoad I do the following:**

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
)

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tool Bar Text", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(confirmSignature))
)

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
)

toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)
toolBar.tintColor = .white
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red



toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

}
else {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

    toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}

exampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

**And as an extension I do the following for when the textfield is selected:**

```
extension myTableViewName: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == exampleTextField {
            let toolBar = UIToolbar()

            view.addSubview(toolBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why will you add toolbar to your view when you have already passed it as input accessory view to textfield?? exampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

Comment: I was not able to change the height constraint when just assigning as accessory view

Comment: I will test this again, but how can I adjust the height of the bar button item?

Comment: check the answer posted now

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of UIBarButtonItem using something like

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tool Bar Text", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(confirmSignature))
button.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
items.append(button)
```

Key is to use customView and applying constraint on it :)

Hope it helps

Comment: The height of the bar button item is still not adjusting, I put your code between the 2 flexible spaces I used

Comment: Any idea why this happening?

Comment: is your toolbar height changing as per your constraint value? 80??

Comment: Yes it is changing to the new constraint but the item is not moving higher

Comment: @jonathan-mense: Can you share screenshots? Its getting harder to imagine what's going wrong there.